# how to generate trusted certificate in the browser

Tags: javascript

I want to make a quiz in browser with out any server side support. After the quiz, if the user passed, I want to generate a certificate of achievement. I want to make sure this certificate isn't phony created by the user. Is there any way to do this pure client side javascript?

Comment: Nothing generated in browser couldn't be faked by a user, after all they can just save your html and js and do what they wish with it.

Comment: Anything you send to a browser is open to attack or compromise. There's is no way you can secure it, or protect against forgery without server involvement.

Comment: Okay, what's the absolute minimum server engament i can get away with. What about a service like firebase? Something secure in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a minimum server-side involvement:

- Answers should be validated on the server. It's a useless quiz if you ship the answers with it to the browser. It's like handing a student a quiz paper, with the answers at the back of the page. Similarly, a few breakpoints in dev tools can reveal where your answers are being compared against the user's answer.
- The actual record of the users accomplishing the quiz should be recorded on the server. The certificate would only be something to represent the achievement. For example, If the certificate is just a printable HTML, I would just edit the page to contain my name and presto! Instant achievement! With a certificate alone, you wouldn't know if it's legit.

Answer (score 0):

No, pure JavaScript can never be trusted since the user can easily influence/control its execution through developer tools that are shipped with most standard browsers.
You have to include server side functionality to make it tamper free.